# Filtering Datagridview From Datagridview Not From Database

Tags: vb.net

i want to filter datagridview on my form..

on the form :

1 datagridview

1 label

1 timer

i have loaded database into datagridview (all data to datagridview)

on my datagridview i have 7 column the last column is date with format dd/MM/yyyy, and now how to filtering datagridview with label, i set this label to date like this

```
Private Sub TimerDate_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles TimerDate.Tick
    Dim FDate As String = Format(Today, "dd/MM/yyyy")
    LblDate.Text = FDate
End Sub
```

and i want to eliminate the other data.. sooo in the end in my datagridview i have data with the last column same as LblDate.text

i dont want to filter datagridview from database.

can someone help me..? thanks.

sorry for my bad english.

this is how i populating data to datagrid

```
Public Class FrmJadwalSidang

Dim ConnString As String = ("Dsn=SqlConn;Server=192.168.100.1;uid=XXX;pwd=XXX;database=DBXXX;port=3306")

Public Function FillData(ByVal Sqlstring As String)
    Dim OdbcConn As OdbcConnection = New OdbcConnection(ConnString)
    OdbcConn.Open()
    Dim MyDataSet As DataSet = New DataSet()
    Dim MyOdbcdAdapter As OdbcDataAdapter = New OdbcDataAdapter()
    MyOdbcdAdapter.SelectCommand = New OdbcCommand(Sqlstring, OdbcConn)
    MyOdbcdAdapter.Fill(MyDataSet)
    Me.DATAGRIDVIEW.DataSource = MyDataSet.Tables(0)
    MyOdbcdAdapter.Dispose()
    MyDataSet.Dispose()
    OdbcConn.Close()
    OdbcConn.Dispose()
End Function

Private Sub FrmMain_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    FillData("Select nomor_perkara, jam_sidang, para_pihak, majelis_hakim_text, panitera_pengganti_text, agenda, tanggal_sidang  from v_jadwal_sidang")
End Sub

End Class
```

SOLVED

```
    Private Sub FrmMain_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        FillData("Select nomor_perkara, jam_sidang, para_pihak, majelis_hakim_text, panitera_pengganti_text, agenda, tanggal_sidang  from v_jadwal_sidang WHERE jadwal_sidang='" & LblDate.text.tostring & "'")
end sub
```

it work. in the end i have to filtering by the sql query..

thanks to someone who gives me the answer.

Comment: How are you populating your datagridview? can you show that code

Comment: is there any easiest way to filter data in a DataGrid like:
datagridview.search
datagridview.eliminateother
or anything like that ..?

Answer (score 0):

if you are using a SqlDataSource, set the FilterExpression of the control.

<del>See this: [How to: Enable Filtering for the SqlDataSource Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/59bfya48%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)</del>

<del>And this: [How to: Connect to an ODBC Database Using the SqlDataSource Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/35c54x95%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)</del>

EDIT : I provided the information for a web application not a winform application.  Please read this for info on how to set up filtering for a BindingSource: [BindingSource.Filter Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.bindingsource.filter.aspx)

Comment: Really? You couldn't be bothered to follow the link?  From the link above: *The SqlDataSource control allows you to filter (sort or select) the results of a query without re-running the query. By adding filtering to a SqlDataSource control, you can change what data is made available by the SqlDataSource after a query has been run, without returning to the database.*

Comment: I do see a concern tho, if you are setting the filter via timer it leads me to believe that you are expecting changed data.  Or are you loading a huge number of rows and only want to hit the DB once and the timer is just some sort of experiment?

Comment: I see you are using an ODBC connection.  You would just have to configure a SqlDataSource with and ODBC connection string.

Comment: @ Fnostro, yes I want to change automatically every day .. for one day, one time load data and one time data filtering. and yes I have more than 50,000 records of data in my database .. so it will be finished by the time LblDate change the date at 0:01 o'clock in the evening.

Comment: I have to modify my answer. you are creating a winform application.  Connecting and Filtering is not done the same way as as a WebForm application which I mistakenly assumed.  To do this in a WinForms app you need to connect to your data base using a control that implements the IBindingListView interface.  [Please read here.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.bindingsource.filter.aspx)

Comment: I just comment and suggest you, you can search by linq, just do like this: Dim HasilFilter = (From a In DataGridView1.Rows Where a.cells("Alamat").value = "Jawa" And a.cells("Nama").value = "Arkan" Order By a.cells("kota").value Descending). And then you can get the result: HasilFilter.count as the rows that you found. and HasilFilter(0).cells("Nama").value as data in column Nama in first element of HasilFilter.

Comment: Now? Sure.  Five years ago, not so much as Linq wasn't in my skill set.  Still I find ASP.NET is remarkably well stocked with functionality but woefully unknown and underutilized.